# How can I change the color of the button a user clicks to green or red depending on if they won or lost

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am wanting the clicked button to change to either red or green based on if the user won the minigame or not, I only know how to disable the buttons after they win or lose, but i want to know how to change the color of the buttons.

I basically wanted to do this so the user knows what button they clicked instead of just turning all of the buttons grey and them not know which one they clicked incase they chose the wrong one.

Thank you!

Code:

```
const { ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, ComponentType, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'basketball',
    aliases: ['bball'],
    description: 'Starts the basketball minigame.',
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        const winArray = ['Nice shot, mate!', 'Deep three, swish!', 'Look at you go, Stephen Curry up in here.', 'Great shot!', 'At the buzzer... GOOOOOOD!', 'You\'re going places, what a shot!', 'Golden, Well done.'];
        const loseArray = ['So close, but so far away', 'Close, but no cigar..', 'Nearly made it', 'Keep trying, you\'ll make it eventually', 'Wow, you got denied', 'Durant could have made that shot...', 'Don\'t give up, mate :/', 'Maybe try a different time?'];
        
        const positions = {
            left: '_ _️️️\n_ _️\n      \n_ _      ',
            middle: '_ _️️️\n_ _     ️\n      \n_ _      ',
            right: '_ _️️️\n_ _           ️\n      \n_ _      ',
        };
        
        let randomized = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(positions).length);
        let gameEnded = false;
        let randomPos = positions[Object.keys(positions)[randomized]];
    
    let leftButton = new ButtonBuilder()
      .setLabel("Left")
      .setCustomId('left')
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary);
    
    let middleButton = new ButtonBuilder()
      .setLabel("Middle")
      .setCustomId('middle')
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary);
    
    let rightButton = new ButtonBuilder()
      .setLabel("Right")
      .setCustomId('right')
      .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary);
    
        const msg = await message.reply({ content: randomPos, components: [new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(leftButton, middleButton, rightButton)] });
        
        function update() {
            randomized = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(positions).length);
            randomPos = positions[Object.keys(positions)[randomized]];
            msg.edit({ content: randomPos, components: [new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(leftButton, middleButton, rightButton)] });
        }
        
        setInterval(() => {
            if(gameEnded == false) return update();
        }, 2000);
    
        const filter = button => {
            return button.user.id === message.author.id
        };
        
        let row = [new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(leftButton, middleButton, rightButton)]
        
        const collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, idle: 15000 });

        const button = await msg.awaitMessageComponent({ filter: filter, componentType: ComponentType.Button, max: 1 });

        if (button.customId !== Object.keys(positions)[randomized]) {
            gameEnded = true;
      leftButton.setDisabled(true);
      middleButton.setDisabled(true);
      rightButton.setDisabled(true);
            await button.deferUpdate();
            await button.editReply({ content: randomPos, components: [new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(leftButton, middleButton, rightButton)] });
            await message.reply({ content: `${winArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * winArray.length)]}`, allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
        }
        else {
            gameEnded = true;
      leftButton.setDisabled(true);
      middleButton.setDisabled(true);
      rightButton.setDisabled(true);
            await button.deferUpdate();
            await button.editReply({ content: randomPos, components: [new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(leftButton, middleButton, rightButton)] });
            await message.reply({ content: `${loseArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * loseArray.length)]}`, allowedMentions: { repliedUser: true } });
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the ButtonStyle to `Success` for a green button and `Danger` for a red button. See https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#button-styles

For example: `leftButton.setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success)`

Then edit the components as you already do.